# Disable all the dates except a specific date in calendar in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datetimepicker

I'd like to disable all the dates of each month except a specific date (say 6th of each month) in a datepicker so that user can only select this specific date of each month in my wpf app. Is it possible? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **ComboBox** if you want the user to select only month and year.
You can do something like this.

```
 <ComboBox Name="Month" Margin="40,100,324,191"  Selected="Month_Selected_1">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Jan"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Feb"></ComboBoxItem>
  </ComboBox>
  <ComboBox Name="Year" Margin="227,100,143,199" Selected="Year_Selected_1" >
        <ComboBoxItem Content="1991"></ComboBoxItem>
  </ComboBox>
```

Then in the **Selected** event.

```
ComboBoxItem typeItem = Year.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
string selectedYear = typeItem.Content.ToString();
```

Instead of adding elements in the XAML ,do it in code behind or use binding.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the property BlackoutDates.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.blackoutdates.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have read this link before, but for my app I want to user can only select 6th of each month in any year. I have no idea whether it's possible.

Comment: @DanielXu: If he can only choose one day, there may be no point in using `DatePicker`?

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev. Yes, you are right. But I dont know how to write code or other methods to achieve the function. I want to only choose one day of each month in any year. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just allow them to choose the month if they know it will always be the same date for all?

Comment: @DanielXu If the user is going to select only one date ,then why do you need a DatePicker,use some dropbox to select the month and Year.

Comment: @Kazuo. This is my desired function, only allow user to choose the month and the year.

Comment: @DanielXu: Maybe you make a selection the month with name in `ComboBox`, year in the form of [`IntegerUpDown`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IntegerUpDown), or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would implement `ComboBox` populated with the names of all the months. Do the same for year if you need to. This way you can tell the user what date the action will take place and just let them choose a month.year.